# How do I change the volume in realtime for my music player (pygame)

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to change the volume of my music in realtime for my music player.

My code:

```
"""Volume Input"""
VolumeLevel = tkr.Scale(player,from_=0,to_=1, 
                        orient = tkr.HORIZONTAL, resolution = 0.1)
def change_vol(_=None):
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(vol.get())
    vol = Scale(
    sound_box,

    
)
```

And here are the action events:

```
def Play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(playlist.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    var.set(playlist.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(VolumeLevel.get())
    print(pygame.mixer.music.get_volume())
    print(VolumeLevel.get())
```

But I don't know how to change the volume while the music is playing, it only changes the volume after I restart the song.

I tried:

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() is True():
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(VolumeLevel.get())
```

But that didn't work it just game me an error.

Comment: You didn't bind the scale to the volume function did you?

Comment: ```
VolumeLevel = tkr.Scale(player,from_=0,to_=1, 
                        orient = tkr.HORIZONTAL, resolution = 0.1)
def change_vol(_=None):
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(vol.get())
    vol = Scale(
    sound_box,
    from_ = 0,
    to = 1,
    orient = tkr.HORIZONTAL ,
    resolution = 0.1,
    
)
```

Comment: bruh add the keyword 'command=change_vol' to the scale. And you don't need the while loop either

Comment: that didn't do anything

Comment: yea i got rid of the while

Comment: You need to also set the argument 'vol' on the change_vol function

Comment: this is the arugemnt isnt it?
    vol = Scale(
    sound_box,
    from_ = 0,
    to = 1,
    orient = tkr.HORIZONTAL ,
    resolution = 0.1,
    command=change_vol
)

Comment: def change_vol(vol, _=None)

Comment: yep ok i changed that but how does that chnage it from not changing the volume while the music is playing

Comment: @MercifulSory pls help

Comment: If you did everything as I said it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use OOP(and I dont think you do based on what you provided), this should be the solution:

```
VolumeLevel = tkr.Scale(player,from_=0,to_=1, 
                        orient = tkr.HORIZONTAL, command=change_vol, resolution = 0.1)
def change_vol(vol, _=None):
    vol *= 100
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(vol)
```